# How to display an image using it's URL with Thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm currently trying to display the actual image instead of it's URL using Java Spring, MySQL and Thymeleaf.  I have a class that gets the url as a string from the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="image")
private String image;

@Column(name="number")
private int number;
```

In the html form I have:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <!-- table headings -->
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Number</th>             
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    
    
    <tbody>
        <!-- Looping over data -->
        <tr th:each="person: ${person}">
        
            <td th:text="${person.name}" />
            <td th:text="${person.image}" />
            <td th:text="${person.number}" />

            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>

</table>
```

What thymeleaf expression or javascript code would I need to display the image at the url as opposed to just the URL string?

Comment: you need something like `<img th:src="${person.image}"></img>`

Answer (score 0):

Before running `th:each="person : ${persons}"`, you can/should also check the list to not be empty: `th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(persons)}".

But to the image question: If your `person` has a field with the URI to the required image (e.g. a relative/absolute path to a data folder or a URL to an image hosted online), you can just "copy" the HTML syntax and add a `th:` in front of it: `<img th:src="${person.imageUrl}" />`

Cheers